# ElasticSearch - How much faster is a Term query than a Match query

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

As **Term** based queries don't have an analysis phase when doing a query and effectively is a retrieval operation rather than a Searching query.
I would assume is would be significantly faster than doing a **match** or **query_string** which understand the underlying mapping and also carry out an analysis/tokenization on the input query first.

I cant find any performance statistics around this and the potential performance gain. Does anyone know of any?

Comment: The best is to test this on your own real data.

Comment: depends on analyzer you are using on match query, but I agree with @AndreiStefan

Comment: This Q&A might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371688/elasticsearch-exact-match-performance-for-very-long-string