# Elasticsearch exact match performance for very long string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a usecase:

I need to extract pieces of information from a single url and save each piece as separate data units to be shown in different pages. When a user visits a data unit in a page, I wish to list all other data units from the same original url.

I intend to define the original url field as a not_analyzed string field and then use exact match to get all the pieces extracted from the original url.

My question is:

The original url could be very long. How efficient is elasticsearch to do exact matching for very long string? Does elasticsearch use some sort of hash algorithm such as git's for long string exact matching?

This usecase will be heavily used thus quite important for me to get an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To match exact documents in a not_analyzed filed You can use a term query which will :

> Find documents that contain the exact term specified in the inverted
>   index.

For example :

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "term" : { "url" : "google.com" } 
  }
}
```

I can't really talk in terms of performance. But this query will match as it is , and it won't apply any transformation to the url as it will be `not_analyzed`.